# Impossible to render variable randomly in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, function

I'm creating a little contest to win prizes.

I have 4 prizes, and I would like a win to happen every 10 days.

I have two problems:

1. When I click the image `.panneau` (to try to win), it always appends the message for when you don't win
2. I don't know how to randomly get the variable indicating a win

Here is my current code:

```
$(".panneau").click(function(){
    if($(".panneau.uncover").length == 0){
        $(this).addClass("uncover");

        $("#intro").hide();

        $.ajax({
            url:'index.php',
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data){
                var nomDuLot ="";
                $('#registration input[type=hidden]').remove();
                $('#registration').append('<input type="hidden" name="myprize" id="myprize" value="'+data.prize+'"/><input type="hidden" value="'+data.id+'" id="id" name="id"/>'+data.nonces);

                if(data.prize=="1"){
                    nomDuLot = "price1";
                }else if (data.prize=="2"){
                    nomDuLot = "price2";
                }else if (data.prize=="3"){
                    nomDuLot = "price3";
                }else if (data.prize=="4"){
                    nomDuLot = "price4";
                }

                setTimeout(function(){
                    if(data.prize=="1" || data.prize=="2" || data.prize=="3" || data.prize=="4"){
                        if(data.prize=="1"){
                            $(".panneau.uncover").append("<p class='long'>Bravo! Vous avez gagné<br><span class='lot'>"+nomDuLot+"</span></p>");
                        }

                        $("#inscription_auto_tirage_au_sort").html("Vous devez vous inscrire pour valider votre gain.<br>En plus, vous participerez automatiquement au tirage au sort pour tenter de gagner 1 set de pneus hiver d’une valeur de 500 €.");
                        $("#etape3 > h2.gagnant").addClass("active");
                    }else{
                        $(".panneau.uncover").append("<p>Vous n'avez<br>&nbsp;pas gagné...</p>");
                        $("#inscription_auto_tirage_au_sort").html("Mais tout n’est pas perdu. Inscrivez-vous pour tenter de gagner blablabla.");
                        $("#etape3 > h2.perdant").addClass("active");

                        // je force le gain à 0
                        $("#myprize").val("0");
                    }

                    $("#etape2").show();
                }, 100);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `index.php` must return the random win in the `prize` key of the response. You are always getting the failure message because none of the win conditions are ever being met (according to your original text "ajax variable randomly [...] i don't know how to do it" ).

   ```
   if(data.prize=="1" || data.prize=="2" || data.prize=="3" || data.prize=="4"){
   ```

   This only shows the win if the response from `index.php` is one of those strings.
2. If you want to only have a win happen every 10 days, you need to store a date somewhere. It could be easy as a text file written to disk, or a row in a database. But somewhere, you'll need to store when the last win was. Then, every time a request is made to `index.php`, check that date against the current date. If the difference is 10 days, randomly generate a win.

   You could also have a list of already won prizes, or simply calculate available prizes on the fly (search directory `/prizes` for a list of files, when a prize is won, delete that file). There's no 100% right or wrong answer to this, but you may want to consider a database to make the problem more maintainable and reportable ("I wonder which prizes are left?", for example, can query a database instead of searching for files).

   Your "every 10 days" logic could be something like:

   ```
   if( $today >= $lastWin + '10 days' ){
       $random = mt_rand( 0, 100000000 );

       if( $random === 569351 ){
           $prize = getRandomAvailablePrize();
       }
   }
   ```

   So one person in a million tries (statistically, it could be more or less) who hits the number "569351" will win a prize when the last win was 10 days ago or more.

Of course, this is all pseudo-code, so the actual implementation will be a bit more in depth, but this is intended to give you an idea. *Don't forget to return the JSON response after a POST as*

```
{ "prize": "[number]" }
```

Where `[number]` is `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, or empty for a loss.

Comment: Thanks rockerest. For the Point 2 i understand the logic. I will work on it but just for the point 1, i'm just beggining learning ajax and  i can't figure it out to return the json response in my php. I made this script grabbing some info on the web. Thanks in advance for your help